# Could light from the Sun be used to power the Breakthrough Starshot microships?

Tags: laser, space-travel, solar-sails

The [Breakthrough Starshot initiative](https://breakthroughinitiatives.org/initiative/3) aims to accelerate a swarm of 16m$^2$-area solar sails to 15% of $c$ using Earth-based lasers in the order of 100GW power in 10 minute bursts. Considering loses from various medium densities and temperatures of the atmosphere [they estimate the sails to receive 60 times the amount light that the Sun provides](https://breakthroughinitiatives.org/forum/5?page=7).
Sunlight in Space is abundant, [8% of its spectrum is ultra-violet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight) light which is more energetic, and has an intensity of around 1000 W/m$^2$.

Could the gigawatt lasers be replaced entirely with an apparatus, in Space, that would be some arrangement of [Fresnel lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens), lenses, mirrors and [crystalline materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar-pumped_laser) so as to forward and beam pumped sunlight to the sails, possibly for longer exposition times?
If yes, what would be the size and composition of such an apparatus, roughly?

Somewhat of a follow up question: what kind of heat would such a beam of sunlight-turned-coherent carry in relation to distance from the spacecraft?

Answer (score 0):

Because of its angular width (low spatial coherence), the sun's light cannot be focused to a small (meter-sized) spot at large distances.  Any kind of lens arrangement can at best form an *image* of the sun.

However, large arrays of photovoltaic cells could certainly be used to power a laser array for Starshot. A laser beam with a large (kilometer-scale) aperture *can* be focused to the requisite meter-scale spot at interplanetary distances because it has very high spatial coherence.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer even though I believe you glossed over the part that pumps sunlight into a laser beam. Looks like I found a positive answer with [Lubin's DESTAR project at Santa Barbara U](https://livestream.com/viewnow/niac2015seattle/videos/105034354)!